# Remove part of a column in dataset R

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a dataset of cricket matches with a range of columns. In one of the columns "MatchID", the value is T20 # xxxx. In order to perform numerical analysis i would like to remove the part which says T20 #. This is an example of how the data looks now:

```
19/10/2017      T20 # 1
26/10/2017      T20 # 2
28/10/2017      T20 # 3
```

The desired output would be

```
19/10/2017      1
26/10/2017      2
28/10/2017      3
```

Any tips?

Answer (score 0):

You can use gsub to replace a regular expression :

```
 df$MatchID = gsub("T 20 \\#", "", df$MatchID)
```

Comment: or `gsub("T20 #", "", df$MatchID, fixed = TRUE) `

Answer (score 0):

Another possible solution:

```r
library(tidyverse)

df %>% 
  mutate(MatchID = str_remove(MatchID, "T20") %>% parse_number)

#>         Date MatchID
#> 1 19/10/2017       1
#> 2 26/10/2017       2
#> 3 28/10/2017       3
```